# ASP classic - JScript: How to escape a single quote (') in a string

Tags: asp-classic, escaping, jscript

OK I'm very embarrassed to ask this, but I am having trouble escaping a single quote from a string in classic ASP. I have tried using `chr(39)` but that doesn't do the trick.

I am not an ASP classic or JScript guy and hadn't even started coding when it became obsolete.

Here is the string (they are ):

```
arrStory[136]['Short'] = 'At the end of May, the group's European partners.';
```

Comment: Do you have try two or three on a row ? `''` ? I find on some old code of me the `\'` as @Alex suggest below.

Comment: Are you sure that '...' & chr(39) & '...' did not work?

Comment: @reporter Like this: ``'At the end of May, the group' & chr(39) & 's European partners.';``??

Comment: Classic ASP is not a language; it's a platform, and multiple scripting languages could be used for the server-side code. VBScript is the most commonly used language and it's what people usually think of when they hear "classic ASP". However, it appears that you are using JScript in your code example. If I'm right, you should edit your question to reflect this, to make sure you get relevant answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the speech marks in JScript are interchangeable - you should be able to use double speech marks (`"`) for the literal itself, while using single speech marks within.

```
arrStory[136]["Short"] = "At the end of May, the group's European partners.";
```

Alternatively try doubling up...

```
arrStory[136]['Short'] = 'At the end of May, the group''s European partners.';
______________________________________________________^
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I learned something new! I love stackoverflow.

Comment: There are actually two answers here. Which answer was the most helpful, @novicePrgrmr?